# Arquillian Jacoco Extension + Jacoco Agent throws lots of exceptions

Tags: junit, jacoco, jboss-arquillian

I have several projects in my organization that have a mix of unit tests.
Half of them use Arquillian, half use Mockito/CDIUnit.

In order to get complete code coverage, we have to run the Jacoco Maven Agent and the Arquillian Jacoco Exception.

It works fine but when we run both, both try to instrument all classes and the Arquillian tests will throw thousands of exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class com/google/common/collect/RegularImmutableAsList is already instrumented.
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.internal.instr.InstrSupport.assertNotInstrumented(InstrSupport.java:89)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.internal.instr.ClassInstrumenter.visitField(ClassInstrumenter.java:55)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.asm.ClassVisitor.visitField(ClassVisitor.java:272)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.asm.ClassReader.readField(ClassReader.java:768)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:689)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:84)
at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:108)
```

My question is, is there any way to include both the maven listener and the Arquillian Jacoco Exension?  Can we configure the Arquillian extension so it doesn't try to re-instrument the classes, or at least doesn't print the stack trace?

I am anticipating someone will say to not mix Arquillian and Mockito, but if that is the only answer, my teams are going to vote to ditch Arquillian.

You can see a small project that is configured with both types of tests included here:
[GitHub - teacurran/alwaysawake-server](https://github.com/teacurran/alwaysawake-server)

And to see an example of the stack traces thrown during build, you can see that here:
[teacurran-alwaysawake-server.master.ci #8 Console](http://jenkins.approachingpi.com/job/teacurran-alwaysawake-server.master.ci/8/console)

- update: it seems that the arquillian-jacoco isn't needed when running the container in embedded mode, this is where I am seeing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Arquillian JaCoCo Extension instruments classes that were already instrumented by the JaCoCo agent, or vise versa.

I don't know for what Arquillian JaCoCo Extension is used and why it needs to perform instrumentation instead of reliance on instrumentation performed by JaCoCo agent, but you can configure [jacoco-maven-plugin goal "prepare-agent"](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html#excludes) that manages [configuration of JaCoCo agent](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html) to exclude classes.

BTW as JaCoCo developer, I'd be interested to hear more about Arquillian JaCoCo Extension. Unfortunately there is not much information on page https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco

Comment: Arquillian based tests don't run in the same process as jUnit so the jUnit listener doesn't pick up the code coverage. the extension allows coverage from these tests to be calculated. I believe it instruments and reports coverage back to junit. In the case where I have regular mockito tests I have to run the agent for those tests. The exceptions thrown aren't a problem but are annoying to see in the logs.

Comment: @TerrenceCurran during execution of your example I see only one Java process that executes tests

Comment: I think I figured it out. Arquillian can be run in remote or embedded mode. I need the jacoco extension when it runs in remote mode because it is a different process. The projects where I'm getting the exception are run in embedded mode so it seems like I don't need the extension at all in this mode.  Thanks for your help.